# Second moment of constants?

Tags: probability, statistics, moment-generating-functions

If instead of a probability distribution I have just three constant valued numbers that are all equally likely to occur, for example 30, 45, 60, how do you find E[X^2]?

Comment: The same way. If $X$ can be 30, 45 or 60 with probs $p, q, r$ resp then take $p30^2+q45^2+r60^2$

Comment: **Hint:** $E(X^2)=\sum_{i=1}^n p_i\cdot x_i^2$.

It seems that $p_i$ has a constant value of $\frac{1}{n}=\frac{1}{3}$

Comment: To verify your solution use the definition of variance in terms of moments: $Var(X)=E(X^2)-E^2(X)=150=2175-2025$